# Convert from string "" to 'double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

im just a newbie in vb.net, i've searched google but i can't connect those to my problem or let say i still can't figure it... Im getting error to "Convert from string "qwerty" to 'double' is not valid".....................qwerty = Username i would really appreciate any help.

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        If Me.txtusername.Tag = 0 Then
            sSQL = "INSERT INTO Instructor ( fname,  lname, mname, [password], [level], Username, Question, answer)"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        Else
            sSQL = "UPDATE Instructor set fname = @first,  lname =  @last, mname = @initial, [password] = @pass, [level] =  @lvl, Question = @quest, answer = @ans WHERE  Username = @user"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@first", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtfname.Text)) > 0, Me.txtfname.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@last", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtlname.Text)) > 0, Me.txtlname.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@initial", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtinitial.Text)) > 0, Me.txtinitial.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtpassword.Text)) > 0, Me.txtpassword.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lvl", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.lbllevel.Text)) > 0, Me.lbllevel.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@quest", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.cmbquestion.Text)) > 0, Me.cmbquestion.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ans", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtanswer.Text)) > 0, Me.txtanswer.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtusername.tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If Me.txtusername.Tag = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
            Me.txtusername.Tag = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End If
        MsgBox("Data has been save.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

heres the perfect code but i change the Contact_ID to Username but i got and error i think its in ".tag" by the way. txtusername.tag is not actually 0..it has already value so it will only choose the UPDATE statement.

```
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        If Me.txtFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
            sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblAddressBook ( last_name,  mid_name, birth_date, gender, home_adr, bus_adr, tel_no, mobile_no, email)"
            sSQL = sSQL & "  VALUES(@last_name,  @mid_name, @birth_date, @gender, @home_adr, @bus_adr, @tel_no, @mobile_no, @email)"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        Else
            sSQL = "UPDATE tblAddressBook set last_name = @last_name,  mid_name =  @mid_name, birth_date = @birth_date, gender = @gender"
            sSQL = sSQL & " ,home_adr = @home_adr, bus_adr = @bus_adr, tel_no = @tel_no, mobile_no = @mobile_no, email =  @email where contact_id = @id"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@last_name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtLastName.Text)) > 0, Me.txtLastName.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mid_name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtMidName.Text)) > 0, Me.txtMidName.Text, DBNull.Value)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@home_adr", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtHomeAdr.Text)) > 0, Me.txtHomeAdr.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bus_adr", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtBusAdr.Text)) > 0, Me.txtBusAdr.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tel_no", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtTelNo.Text)) > 0, Me.txtTelNo.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile_no", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtMobNo.Text)) > 0, Me.txtMobNo.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtEmail.Text)) > 0, Me.txtEmail.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'If the record is new then we have to get its ID so that we can edit it rightaway after the insertion.
        If Me.txtFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
            'Set textbox tag property with the ID of new record
            Me.txtFirstName.Tag = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End If
        MsgBox("Data has been save.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Do this error happen when you insert or Update the record?? Also confirm if all the columns in Database are of ````DataType varchar```` as you are sending all the parameters as Varchar.

Comment: yah, syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: on the other program i've made, i had successfully add and save into my dabase ... its just that I changed the "ID" into Username... where ID is in numeric. im really confused.

Comment: You are not inputting any data in the INSERT INTO? All the parameters refer to (@)strings present in UPDATE.

Comment: Is 'lvl' a numeric column in the DB?  If so you need to convert the label text to a numeric value.  It could also be .Tag which may not be text.

Comment: If Username is numeric, you need to cast ````txtusername```` value to ````Int```` and also change the ````datatype```` to ````Int```` instead of ````varchar````

Comment: well i missed the "VALUE to INSERT" and lbl is not numeric, i remove numeric and made Username as primary key

Comment: Convert from string “” to 'double' is not valid still exist to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `VALUES` portion of your `INSERT` statement, try it like this:

```
INSERT INTO Instructor (fname,  lname, mname, [password], [level], Username, Question, answer) 
VALUES (@fname, @last, @initial, @pass, @lvl, @user, @quest, @ans)
```

You are also not casting the `Tag` value properly in your parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = CType(txtusername.tag, String)
```

Comment: sorry I loss connection. i used  CType(txtusername.tag, String) but still exist i think the problem is in .tag

Comment: Please post the code where you are setting the `.Tag` property value.

Comment: there, i posted the original code. :) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I changed the User_ID which is in numeric into "Username "

Comment: So `Tag` is empty (`""`) when it is attempted to be used in the parameter?

Comment: nope.. the "txtusername.tag is connected to my datagridview in FORM1 that will fetch and display all the data into the FORM2 textboxes.   and its actually working. the only problem is when i "Update or save the data" without changes still the error persist.

Comment: i have the complete code if u want... i'll upload it for you.   txtusername.tag is not really empty, it is connected to the other form1 that will help to display all data into textboxes and it actually work the only problem is when i choose to "update".. i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I missed  If Me.txtFirstName.Tag = 0 Then to Me.txtusername.Tag.ToString().Trim() = "0" and now its working :)